# extracting library to different path while using ar(1) command in makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to compile some c codes with library. And I need to create library to different path before use it. My makefile is like:

```
CFLAGS = -O3

all: libexm.a derle 

OBJS = b.o c.o d.o e.o

libexm.a: $(OBJS)
    ar ru libexm.a $(OBJS)
    ranlib libexm.a

clean:
    rm -f core *.o libexm.a

.SUFFIXES: .c .o
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I ./include/ -c ./src/$*.c

derle:
    gcc -g -I ./include/ -o ./bin/test ./src/a.c ./lib/libexm.a -lm
```

a is mine main c file. b, c, d and e are library's ones as you can see. I need to store them in exactly where they are belong to. Like headers must be in "include" file, objects in "objs" etc. . And most important thing is my library(.a) must be in "lib" file after compiled. My main problem is how can I compile my library with using "ar" command and store it to under "lib" file. And of course it's should take objects files from "objs" file.
My file order is like:[image]

EDIT : made it this way and now it works.

```
INC = ./include/
BIN = ./bin/
SRC = ./src/
LIB = ./lib/
OBJS = ./objs/
libOBJS = b.o c.o d.o e.o

hepsi: $(libOBJS) libexm.a
    gcc -g -I $(INC) -o $(BIN)a $(SRC)a.c $(LIB)libexm.a -lm

libexm.a: $(addprefix $(OBJS), $(libOBJS))
    ar rcs $(LIB)libexm.a $+
    ranlib $(LIB)libexm.a

$(libOBJS): %.o: $(SRC)%.c
    gcc -o $(OBJS)$@ -I $(INC) -c $<
```

Comment: `ar ru lib/libexm.a $(OBJS)`? That is, put the directory into the command? Or probably better still, make `lib/libxm.a` the target for the rule.

Comment: @kaylum command cannot see object files it needs. There is no object files of b,c,d,e 's after compile. I don't know where did I do wrong.

Comment: Make `lib/libxm.a` the target for the rule, definitely, since that's what you in fact want to build.  And as a general best practice, in the recipe use the automatic variable `$@` to refer to the rule's target, rather than retyping its name.

Comment: Additionally, your `.c.o` rule is all wrong.  A suffix rule builds files with the target suffix from files whose names are related by replacing the target suffix with the source suffix.  That includes any directory names in the target name, so suffix rules are never applicable to building a target from a source in a different directory.  The details of the recipe are wrong, too, but that hardly matters because you probably can't use a suffix rule for your particular purposes.  Have a look into pattern rules, instead.  They are more flexible.